# usage: make a rule of

Tags: phrase-usage

The Cambridge Dictionary Online defines "prescribe" as follows:

to tell someone what they must have or do, or to **make a rule of something**

But I'm wondering whether the boldfaced part is natural. Can we say the following?

> The government will **make a rule of** a 4-day workweek.

I cannot find such examples on Google.

Comment: They mean 'make a rule about something'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you, but I don't understand what you mean. Is the "4-day" example OK?

Comment: I thought you were asking whether _make a rule  of_ was an idiomatic phrase (it isn't particularly). Governments pass laws rather than making rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that Cambridge is necessarily suggesting a natural phrasing, but rather just describing what the word means. A more natural phrasing, using your example with a slight modification, would be:

> The Department of Labor will make the four-day workweek a rule.

I suppose you could also say "make a rule of the four-day workweek," but that doesn't sound quite as natural to me. That may be because the expression "make a rule of" something has another meaning: it expresses somebody's strict practice of doing something, e.g.:

> I make a rule of brushing my teeth immediately after I eat.

This means that I strictly brush my teeth immediately after I eat (even if it's not literally a rule).